# Use remote Tomcat/Solr for BlueSpice ExtendedSearch

Tags: mediawiki, configuration

Is it possible to configure the BlueSpice ExtendedSearch extension to connect to a remote Apache Tomcat/Solr instance instead of installing all of that on the same machine that runs BlueSpice?

I looked through the [install guide for ExtendedSearch](https://en.help.bluespice.com/wiki/Setup:Installation_Manual/Webservices/Extended_Search), but I couldn't find any mention of this as an option.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looking at the [BlueSpice 3 Roadmap](https://blog.bluespice.com/2017/02/23/coming-soon-with-bluespice-3-a-look-at-the-road-map/) it looks like ExtendedSearch is [being deprecated](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/rEBSE592af95b0202e6d755b934cd4db46a974c4fdba0) in favor BlueSpiceExtendedSearch which will leverage Elastic instead of Solr. That said, it doesn't seem worth it to figure out a custom configuration for ExtendedSearch. I will leave this open for now in case someone else wants to contribute a solution.